# How do I debug an AttributeGraph crash on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

Any suggestions on how to debug this crash.  I have no idea what is causing this or how to even start debugging this.  I am guessing it might be SwiftUI related.

There is a list of objects in a GridView and a details panel showing the image for the object and the crash occurs when selecting and/or deselecting an object in a particular sequence.

[image]

Comment: Seems like you have a block of code that’s making infinite calls, a while loop may be, or  you might have implemented recursion functionality in your code.

Comment: @TusharSharma I found this seems to have been caused by switching from using a NavigationView to using a HSplitView instead.  When I go back to using NavigationView the problem goes away. ?!? A bug in SwiftUI maybe - if it was an infinite loop it would surely still manifest with NavigationView ?